# Why is $B^2 = \mathbb{I}_2$ where $B = T^{-1}AT$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am currently studying group representations. And I know that two If $\phi:G \to GL(n,F)$ is a representation of $G$ over $F$ and if $\gamma:G \to GL(m,f)$ is also a representation of $G$ over $F$we say that $\phi$ is equivalent to $\gamma$ if $n=m$ and their exists an invertible $n \times n $ matrix $T$ such that $$\gamma(a) = T^{-1}\phi(a)T$$

And so for a simple example we consider the group $G = \big<a:a^2 = 1 \big>$ and let

$$ 
A = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -5 & 12 \\ 
    -2 & 5 
   \end{bmatrix}
$$
we observe that $A^2 = \mathbb{I}_2$, now $\phi(a^n) = A^n$ is a representation where $1 \leq n \leq 2$.

Now define an invertible matrix
$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

then $$T^{-1}AT = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so we obtain a representation $\gamma$ of $G$ such that $\gamma(1) = \mathbb{I}_2$ and $\gamma(a) = T^{-1}AT$.

Now $\gamma$ is equivalent to $\phi$ because $\gamma(a) = T^{-1}\phi(a)T$ for all $a \in G$

Now here is my question, why is it that $B = T^{-1}AT$ has the property that $B^2 = I_2$. I mean we can obtain infinite equivalent representations that way for $G_2$ we just get an invertible matrix $T$ and then we calculate $B = T^{-1}AT$ and then we would have that $B^2 = I_2$ and then we define a representation just like we did ?

But why is it true that $B^2 = I_2$ when we do that ?

Comment: I'll add a little bit to this. You chose a matrix $A$ such that $A^2=I$ because it represents the group for which $a^2=1$. The representation $B$ is equivalent precisely because it also has the property $B^2=I$, so it can represent the group $G$ as well. In other words, the definition of an equivalent representation is defined as so because it literally is an "equivalent" representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer isn't anything too deep, here.  Note that
$$
B^2 = (T^{-1}AT)(T^{-1}AT) = T^{-1}A(TT^{-1})AT 
= T^{-1}A^2 T = T^{-1}IT = T^{-1}T = I
$$
More generally: if $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $B = T^{-1}AT$, then
$$
p(B) = T^{-1}p(A)T
$$

Comment: That was pretty easy !! :D thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!  It's useful to note that the only matrix similar to $I$ is $I$ itself, and that the same is true for the (scalar) multiples of $I$.  In particular, these matrices form the center of the group of invertible matrices under multiplication.